# Calling a method, but won't return the values. Java

Tags: java, variables, object, methods

So I have an assignment where I have to make a bank account. Long story short I have a class that has your actions (deposit, withdraw etc) in methods, and a Driver which would fills in the blanks (i.e client name, balance etc.) as well it calls the methods from the other class.

Now my issue. For an example, when I deposit, my variables send fine to the method and do the math correctly and have the correct balance, but returning the balance's new value is an issue. It is still the same value it was before in the driver.

This is my driver's deposit code

```
 String deposit1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How much would you like to deposit?");
 int deposit = Integer.parseInt (deposit1);
 myBank.getDeposit(deposit, balance);
```

This is my deposit method code

```
 public void getDeposit(int deposit, int balance)
{
    if (deposit<0)
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Number");
        deposit=0;
    }
    balance =balance + deposit;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, can't seem to find any solutions and I've been stuck for some time

Thanks

P.S This is my first time on these forums so sorry if I did anything wrong

P.P.S My java knowledge isn't that high, still just a beginner

Edit:
We have learned instance variables as well as touched a little upon return statements, we haven't learned anything about passby. By return I mean giving the driver the correct value, sorry if that threw you off

Edit2: Thank youuu so much user1710742, finally got it. I understand now. Makes sense

Comment: You need to ask your instructor about something called "return value." (And possibly "instance field" and maybe "pass by value", but it's kinda hard to guess what you really want to do here.)

Comment: Possible dupe of [Is-Java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: That the method is named `get`-Something but returns `void` would be an indication that something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are attempting to change a copy of the variable, not the exact one that you gave to the method. When you exit the method, the copy is destroyed, and you are left with just the unchanged original value.

The method can't return a value unless you tell it to with a `return` statement.

```
public int getDeposit(int deposit, int balance)
{
    if (deposit<0)
    {
        System.out.println ("Invalid Number");
        deposit=0;
    }
    return balance + deposit;
}
```

call with:
`int total = myBank.getDeposit(deposit, balance);`

Comment: While an answer, I think the OP would actually be better of using an instance variable here.  Best to ask the instructor what the assignment was I think.

Comment: OP did say that "returning" was the issue. However it is possible OP was using the term incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new variable call **dep** with int data type :

```
int dep = myBank.getDeposit(deposit, balance);
```

after that change your method type from void to int and add return statement of variable that you want :

```
public int getDeposit(int deposit, int balance)
{
  if (deposit<0)
  {
    System.out.println ("Invalid Number");
    deposit=0;
  }
  balance =balance + deposit;
  return balance;
}
```

Comment: At least add _some_ sort of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totaly sure if you are actually doing what you want to do..
To me, it seems like you want to create a class called Bank and have a private variable there, called ballance. then methods for manipulating that value..

```
public static class Bank{
    private int balance = 0;

    // this method won't return any value. it will only change
    // the banks internal state, therefor we write "void"!
    public void deposit(int deposit){
        if(deposit<0){
            // using System.err instead of System.out will be handled differently
            // by java. It is meant to be used for error messages. some consoles make
            // these texts pop out more (like displyaing it in read)
            System.err.println ("Invalid Number");
        }else{
            // balance += deposit is a short way of writing balance = balance + deposit;
            balance += deposit;
        }
    }

    // this method will return an int value to who ever called it.
    // you can tell, because it says int after public
    public int getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
}
```

And then a main method which handles the bank:

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
bank.deposit(5);
bank.deposit(8);

int balance = bank.getBalance(); // will be 13

System.out.println("balance is "+balance);
```

More on System.err can be found in the [oracle docs about System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err)

Hope I could help

Comment: and how can you get a returning value of a method without printing out what is inside of a method? Because I am trying to return an object value in my method, but when I assign method to a variable, like `Object x = call_method();` what happens is the whole method is called again. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

start with the basics of the language.  Yet, Keep in mind that understanding the problem is the only true way to reach the right solution. Don't let the language get in the way of the logic.  You'll get the syntax down fast enough.  You've got a good start.  It's easy to get drawn into just finding A solution, instead of finding THE solution.  The method of solving the problem is more important than having an answer.  Try the link below for the basics on the return value.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_methods.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not name your method `getDeposit()` since the return type is `void`. Instead, just name it `deposit()`, because you actually do an action.
2. Use a private instance variable named `balance`, in your Bank class.
3. Use a getter for your `balance` field.

This snippet should work:

```
public class BankAccount {

    private int balance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

        String deposit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How much would you like to deposit?");
        account.deposit(Integer.parseInt (deposit));

        deposit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How much would you like to deposit?");
        account.deposit(Integer.parseInt (deposit));

        System.out.println(account.getBalance());

    }

     public void deposit(int deposit){
         if (deposit < 0){
             System.out.println ("Invalid Number");
         }else{
             balance += deposit;
         }   
     }

     public int getBalance(){
         return balance;
     }
}
```